# getting stuck at "We can't verify your phone number right now. Try again later." as i am creating a new account for google play console

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

i have tried so many times to create  an account for google play console but as i get to mobile number i get stcuk here. please help me as per attched screen shot.

i have tried different email but the problem still persist.

Comment: Hello:)
This thread can help you
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/206281945/we-can-t-verify-your-phone-number-right-now-try-again-later-play-console?hl=en